# How to change mesh's position in function animate() in three.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I have a simple mesh in three.js (implemented into three.js-master\examples\webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html):

```
function init() {
...
...
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 16 ); 
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0x8888ff} ); 
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere.position.set(10, 10, 10);
    scene.add(sphere);
```

I'd like to change this mesh's position in function animate();

I've tried several things, but None of the below example was working:

1.:

```
sphere.position.set = new THREE.Vector3(20, 20, 20);
```

2.:

```
 sphere.position.set(20, 20, 20);
```

3.:

```
sphere.position.x += 1;
```

4.:

```
sphere.translateX(50);
```

The result is a black screen every time.

The strange thing is that I can change camera and light positions in the same area of code:

```
                pointLight.position.set(10, 20, 03);
                camera.position.set(12, 44, 13);
                camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(33, 45, 54));
```

However the position.set of a mesh fails.
Is it possible to change a mesh's position in function animate()?

I've tried:

```
"sphere.position.x = 20;"
```

the result is a black window.

Below you can see the detailed console log:

The log's comment for the line above "sphere.position.x = 20;":

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined"
```

Other details of the log for this issue:

```
"animate @ index_final.html:260
(anonymous function) @ index_final.html:98
parse @ ColladaLoader.js:225
request.onreadystatechange @ ColladaLoader.js:113"
```

Comment: `sphere.position.x = newValue` should be fine (not sure about the '+=')... maybe there's another error. Does the browser console tell you anything?

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sphere` variable that references the mesh is not in the scope of the `animate()` function.
Make it a global variable by removing the `var`:

`sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);`

Then in `animate()` calling `sphere.position.set(20, 20, 20);` should do it,

or if you want to animate the movement: `sphere.position.x += 1;`

---

Disclaimer: keep in mind *global variables* should be avoided because they are *evil* >:)

Comment: Your suggestion is working perfectly. This is the solution.